# Detect in application the Google Play origin

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I would like to know if it's possible to find out in application from which Google Play Store/country it was downloaded.

The solution like - after someone download app we get GPS info to find out where the user is located are is not an option. I am asking about Google Play Services / Google Play Store API that can be used to achieve this.

This is my edge case - User move from France to the UK and download my app from France Google Play Store, so in my app, I will have information that user is using Google Play Store from France.

Comment: Suppose that I am in the UK, Google's servers are in the USA, and I use the Play Store Web site to install an app on a device that is presently in Mozambique. What, in your model, is "the Google Play origin"?

Comment: I think that USA, but this is very difficult situation.

Comment: What about solution - have different application names for UK and for France. Then in app ask about application name and find out from which store it was downloaded? @CommonsWare

Comment: If by "application name" you mean `applicationId`, while that is possible, it means that you will need to manage N different Play Store listings, one per country that you are worrying about. That will have impact on your marketing as well, as now there will not be a single Play Store listing to drive traffic towards. I recommend that you not worry about any of this, and simply ask the user what country they want to associate with their installed copy of your app.

Comment: @CommonsWare What about changing settings in google play -  store listing. To have two different names of app for France - having App France and for UK having App UK. After app is installed the name will be taken from store or from 'local' string values?

Comment: After the app is installed, the name comes from your `android:label` attribute in your `<application>` element of your manifest, regardless of where the app is installed from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that not all phones come with Google Play Services!

[Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish) should be able to present you with that data.

Select your application from the Dashboard and there you should see a map with the current active install-base by country. If you want to dive more deep into that data, go to the Statistics tab or click 'Details' on the top right corner.

[image]

If you need more advanced statistics, like dropout rate, open rate, etc. I suggest you look into a third party platform like Adobe Analytics, Google Firebase Analytics, etc.

Comment: So let's assume that I can use Google Firebase Analytics. Is there any API to use it in mobile app and find out which Google Play I used?

Comment: No, you can't identify any app if it has been installed from Google Play or another source, but Google is planning to add such meta data to the manifest in the future: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html?m=1 (see Security metadata in early 2018) although that may be kept private and I see no way you could associate it with the store's region.

Comment: @boski you should be able to tell which countries you get it downloaded from in both Google Play Console or Firebase Analytics as I mentioned in my answer below. If I have a Danish Google account but travel to the UK, I'm still downloading it via the Danish Play Store hence the download per country should indicate that accordingly. You could try to reach out to Google Support to get further clarification on what country represents in their analytics.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in the application. No such API exists either server side or client side. The [Google Play licensing library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html) will tell you whether the app came from Play or not, but will not tell you the user's country.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18433588)

Comment: It does answer the question. The author asked if it was possible (not how to do it). It is not possible, and that is the definitive answer.